# Jhipster logging

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new at JHipster, I would like to add ip, url, method, etc. append to the log file as json when ever get api call, where should I start?  my  logback-spring.xml look like this

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>90</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <charset>utf-8</charset>
        <Pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}.%M\(%line\): %msg%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>512</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</appender>
```

Comment: You should write your own filter. Then you'll need an appender.

Comment: Yes you can do it with a filter that writes your values in the MDC so that you don't need another appender.